# Is the following a subspace, where $f(t) \in C^{1}[0,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is probably an easy question, but I just want to check my understanding of it.

Here it is:

Let $f(t) \in C^{1}[0,1]$. Is the subset of functions $f(t)$ such that

$\frac{df}{dt}+\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt+c = 0$

where $c\ne0$ is some constant, a subspace? If not, how could you make this a subset a subspace.

My reasoning is that this is not a subspace, stating that the zero vector, $f(t) = 0$, is not contained in the subset because of $c$. To make it a subspace, I would let $c = 0$.

However, I'm questioning whether $f(t)=0$ is the zero vector. (I'm not sure what it is).
Any insight would be appreciated. This is also not homework.

Comment: A zero vector is a vector with the property that $0+a = a$ for all other vectors $a$ (i.e. it is the identity for addition). $f(t) = 0$ is indeed the zero vector.

Comment: That all looks correct to me.  "How could you make this a subset a subspace?" is a pretty vague question but the answer you have given is probably what they are expecting.  (Another answer: turn the last $+$ into $\times$.)

Comment: Is the constant $c$ independent of the function $f$? Or is the proposed subspace the set of $f\in C^1([0,1])$ such that there exists some $c\ne0$, depending on $f$, for which that equality holds?